# Stop execution of a method as soon as one IF condition is met in c#

Tags: c#

I got a couple of if statements. What I want is, as soon as one condition is met, I should get out of the method. I will be using this if statements on filtering data for a datagridview or report. With my code below, it doesn't do this. It seems to go through all conditions. As soon as it finds a condition that meets it, the program executes it and proceeds to another if statement and if it sees that it meets the condition also, it too gets executed.
I think this is pretty basic for you. I don't remember or know how I should do this.

```
private void btnRoute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbWithRoute.Checked)
        {
            // StartSearch(txtRoute.SelectedValue.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(@"route");
        }
        if (cbWithRoute.Checked && cbWithWholeSeller.Checked)
        {
            //StartSearch(txtRoute.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtWholeSeller.SelectedValue.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(@"route wholeseller");
        }
        if (cbWithRoute.Checked && cbWithCustomer.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"route customer");
        } 
        if (cbWithRoute.Checked && cbWithWholeSeller.Checked && cbWithDate.Checked)
        {
            //StartSearch(txtRoute.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            //    txtWholeSeller.SelectedValue.ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text).ToShortDateString(),
            //    Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text).ToShortDateString());
            MessageBox.Show(@"route wholseller date");
        }
        if (cbWithRoute.Checked && cbWithCustomer.Checked && cbWithDate.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"route date customer");
        }
        if (cbWithRoute.Checked && cbWithWholeSeller.Checked && cbWithDate.Checked && cbWithCustomer.Checked)
        {
            //StartSearch(txtRoute.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            //    txtWholeSeller.SelectedValue.ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text).ToShortDateString(),
            //    Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text).ToShortDateString(), txtCustomer.SelectedValue.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(@"route wholeseller date customer");
        }
        //else
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(@"Check criteria to search.");
        //}

    }
```

I commented the true code and replaced it with message boxes to show me what checkboxes are checked. Thank you.

Comment: You mean like **else if**? Of course, you would need to rearrange your conditions, else method will exit as long as `cbWithRoute.Checked` is true without looking at the other checks

Comment: If you change to if else if then you gain the benefit of not checking each of the conditions and no return statement is needed. You might also consider nesting with the first condition as the outer-most if statement so you don't have to check it again and again.

Comment: The option cbWithRoute.Checked by itself is the default option and should be the last item tested in the method not the first.  Then adding a return in each if statement will solve the issue.

Comment: @jdweng: Exactly. That's what I did before your comment and it's working now. ^_^. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Else-if is the concept you need. Like below.

```
if (cbWithRoute.Checked)
    {
        // StartSearch(txtRoute.SelectedValue.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(@"route");
    }
    else if (cbWithRoute.Checked && cbWithWholeSeller.Checked)
    {
        //StartSearch(txtRoute.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtWholeSeller.SelectedValue.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(@"route wholeseller");
    }
```

Comment: If I am to use the else-if then I should be removing the return on each statement. That's what I did. I removed the returns and added the else-if but it does exactly what placing a return do.

Comment: Placing multiple returns in a method is not considered as good practice. So to avoid having multiple exit else if can be considered

Comment: It's not enough that I put in the else if. I coded the statement in reverse. I started with the most number of conditions to the least and it worked. @Irshad: I used your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Where ever you want it to stop executing, place the following line

```
return;
```

I wont assume to understand the business logic behind the checks but you may also want to read up on `else` statements and `else if`

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. If I place a return on each statement, say I check cbWithRoute and cbWithCustomer, it executes the first if statement and gets out of the method which in fact is wrong. It should just skip cbWithRoute.Checked and the second statement and execute the third statement since that is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Since your method retrun type is `void` add a `return` to end of all the if conditions like below;

```
if (cbWithRoute.Checked)
{
    // StartSearch(txtRoute.SelectedValue.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(@"route");
    return;
}
if (cbWithRoute.Checked && cbWithWholeSeller.Checked)
{
    //StartSearch(txtRoute.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtWholeSeller.SelectedValue.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(@"route wholeseller");
    return;
}
```

and so on....

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. If I place a return on each statement, say I check cbWithRoute and cbWithCustomer, it executes the first if statement and gets out of the method which in fact is wrong. It should just skip cbWithRoute.Checked and the second statement and execute the third statement since that is the correct one.

Comment: Then you should organize all your if conditions so that how your program should execute them. Prioritize the conditions please.